# How to deploy a node.js application on AWS whose source code is inside a custom gitlab repository ?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, deployment, gitlab

I have a node js application whose source code is residing in a gitlab repository. This gitlab server is maintained by my company. Hence anyone outside the company network has to access the gitlab repo through VPN only.

Now I want to deploy the node js app in an AWS EC2 instance (t2.micro possibly). 
I have seen that if the source code is in github, we can install git in the AWS EC2 instance and pull the code directly. But with the code residing in a gitlab repo in my company network what can be done to deploy the app in AWS ?

And how shall updates for my server be handled ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VPN connection to your VPC and your Company network so that the Instance in your network can access your company network directly.

Here is the AWS documentation for your reference [VPN Connections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html)